# Advantage of Poisson model over Cox PH model for analyzing first event?

Tags: cox-model, poisson-regression, incidence-rate-ratio

For analysis of the first event, I am wondering if Poisson model has any advantage over Cox model, besides some people find rate ratio easier to interpret than hazard ratio?

I notice some people use Poisson model to analyze treatment effect in different strata of time. For example, for COVID studies, they can analyze the effect during a certain variant period. Or they can analyze whether the effect remains the same from 3-6 month compared to the first 3 month. Are these achievable by the Cox model too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the tradeoff between assuming a particular functional form for a relationship, which can be more powerful if it actually holds, versus working with a semi- or non-parametric model that doesn't depend so strongly on guessing the functional form correctly.

A Poisson model assumes constant hazards over time. It might be fit via the corresponding exponential model for survival times. A Cox model allows the hazard to change arbitrarily over time, only requiring (in its simplest form) that the *ratios* of hazards associated with covariates be the same over time. If you suspect that hazard ratios change over time, however, a Cox model can be adapted to evaluate that possibility. See the [R time dependence survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought. People often use Poisson regression for mortality rate etc. I am just wondering whether there is any advantage of Cox model. We can rarely assume the rate is constant over time. To me the advantage is limited.